# quisiera poder regresar el ciclo pero incluyendo a este codigo la ecuacion while (edad>0)

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer que en este código cuando sea mayor que 25 y menor que cero (números negativos) me regrese al inicio del programa **"escribir edad"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{

  int edad;
  do{
    cout<<"escribir edad "; cin>>edad;
    if (edad>0 && edad<=25) {
      cout<<"su edad es " <<edad;
    }
    else if (0>edad)
    {
      cout<<"la edad no es correcta \n";
    }
    else if (edad>25)
    {
      cout<<"la edad no es correcta \n";
    }
  }
  while(edad>25);
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;

  getch();
}
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que quiero hacer que en este codigo cuando sea mayor que 25 y menor que cero (numeros negativos) me regrese al inicio del programa "escibir edad".

Comment: Es imposible que se cumpla que un número sea mayor que 25 y menor que 0, seguro intentaste decir mayor que 25 **O** menor que cero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intentar así . sí en el while ya está la condición del mayor que 25 `>25` y menor que 0 `<0`, no es necesario volver a realizar la comprobación con `if` , para validar esto sería así.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

 main()
 {
 int edad=0;
 do{
   cout<<"escribir edad "; 
   cin>>edad;
  }
  while(edad>25 || edad <0);
  cout<<"su edad es " <<edad;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias esa era la respuesta que necesitaba para el codigo

Comment: Por curiosidad ¿por qué escogiste or (`||`) en lugar de and (`&&`)?

Comment: Porqué solo se podrá cumplir una condición y no las dos. Jamás saldría del ciclo con `&&` ya que no existe un número mayor que 25 y menor que 0

Answer (score 0):

Para esto, se puede usar la negación de una expresión válida, con el signo de exclamación `!`.

- Esta expresión es si la edad es entre 0 y 25. `edad>0 && edad<=25`
- Para negar eso sin cambiar el signo mayor o menor `>`, se puede usar el `!`, de esta manera, agrupando entre paréntesis y usando el signo de exclamación. `!(edad>0 && edad<=25)`

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int edad;
    while( !(edad>0 && edad<=25) )
    {
        cout<<"La edad no es correcta.\n";
        cout <<"Escribir edad: "; cin>>edad;
    }
    cout<<"Su edad es " <<edad;
    system("PAUSE");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```